# Displaying rownum in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, criteriaquery

My requirement is to select `row_number()` along with other fields from select clause. I am able to execute it with `entitymanager.createNativeQuery()`. Here I can frame my query and execute but in this case I am unable to use Criteria builder and Specification APIs.

I want to execute below query:
`select * from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id) rownum,* FROM Table c) as d Where <DynamicCondition>`

Need to create DynamicCondition with help of criteria builder using which I can build criteria with all available functions of CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder.

Please suggest.

Also is it possible with custom SQL function by creating SQL function?

I am trying to create it as :

```
 metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "getrownum",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                    "row_number() over(?) as ?",
                    StandardBasicTypes.STRING) {
            });
```

And want to use it as :

```
 Expression rownum = criteriaBuilder.function("getrownum", 
 String.class,expression,expression);
```

But unable to use this function in Criteria as I don't know how to create and pass expression arguments. Any Suggestions?

Comment: hello! isn't rownum the index of overy item in the returned list from `entityManager.createQuery(yourCriteria).getResultList()`?

Comment: Yes it is, If my query retrieves 10 records, it will have row numbers as 1 to 10 sequentially. So if I have rownum in my entity, and execute native query, it maps to it and execute. and I am getting result as expected. But I need to do it with CriteriaBuilder to get benifit of all functions it provides.